# Windows Server 2016 Backup and restore with previous dates for recover file

Tags: windows, backup-restoration

I am using Windows Server 2016 for windows backup.
My backup is a full server backup scheduled every day at 10:00 PM.
A user asked for a three day old file but at the time of recovery or restore only last date showing and other dates are disabled.
Any idea how to recover the file?
In Windows Server 2008 I can get backup of multiple dates but in Windows Server 2016 I am stuck.

Comment: It all depends on how the backup configuration was made.
You can leave multiple restore points or leave only 1 restore point.

Comment: Thanks for reply in windows server 2016 std. Windows Backup there is no way for multiple restore points. Can you please refer me suitable link for study???

Comment: If you want to restore files the simplest way is to configure VSS with as many restore points as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server Backup only allows for complete backups to be restored. This means that users can’t simply recover a specific file, a specific table, or a specific mailbox from the past. They will have to recover the entire server making it a time consuming process, completely inefficient for file-level recovery.

If you want **file recovery**, you can use VSS and configure restore points on a daily basis or on a period that is convenient to you. For example, for file servers I use 2 restore points per day: 1 at 0000 and one at 1200.

To configure VSS:

- Open Services and Make sure Volume Shadow Copy service is in [running] state
- Access DISK MANAGMENT or right click on a disk drive
- Right click on the volume (not the disk) and select PROPERTIES
- Select the SHADOW COPIES tab
- Click on the disk you want Shadow Copies enabled for
- Click ENABLE button
- Click YES (in popup window)
- Click SETTINGS button and make sure it is as you expect (like daiy)

You then can recover any file in the limit of how many restore points you configured just by exploring the previous version of that location.